# error 1215: CANNOT ADD FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT ; Composite Foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am getting ERROR CODE 1215: cannot add foreign key constraint for the child table.
Parent table has composite primary key. I want to use that composite primary key as foreign key in the child table.
Please guide me.

PARENT TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE health.procedures(
    Specialty varchar(40),
    Procedure_Name varchar(60),
    PRIMARY KEY (Procedure_Name, Specialty)
);
```

CHILD TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE health.procedureProvided(
    specialization varchar(40),
    procedure_name varchar(60),
    Insurance_ID int REFERENCES health.insurance (idInsurance),
    Hospital_ID int REFERENCES health.hospital (idHospital) ,
    Doctor_ID int REFERENCES health.doctor( idDoctor) ,
    CONSTRAINT procedures_fk foreign key (specialization,procedure_name)references health.procedures(Specialty,Procedure_Name) ,
    PRIMARY KEY (specialization, procedure_name, Insurance_ID, Hospital_ID, Doctor_ID)
);
```

Comment: Looks to me like the PK on `procedures` is not a composite key, just has `procedure_name` in it.

Comment: If the PK of procedures is just procedure_name, then the FK on the child table should also be just procedure_name.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add Specialty to primary key of  Parent Table. PRIMARY KEY (procedure_name, Specialty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying a foreign key that is invalid.  Your primary key is procedure_name in health.procedure, but you are trying to create a composite foreign key in health.procedureProvided.  You can't create that as a foreign key as the column Specialty in the master table is not part of the primary.  A foreign key must contain all the columns in the contributing table's primary key but cannot contain values that are not in that primary key.  You have three real options.  1.  Specify Specialty as being a component of the primary key in procedure.  Unfortunately that means the procedure will not necessarily by unique, it will be unique by specialty.  2. add a surrogate key - a system generated sequence value, uuid or something else (timestamps are not recommended).  3. Create validation tables valid_procedures and valid_specialties and use the table health.procedure as an intersection between those to provide valid procedures and correlated specialties and then you could migrate the entire primary key.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry for error in parent table. I corrected error in Parent table. However, I still do get the same error 1215.

Comment: The order of the foreign key columns is important.  Gotta love MySQL :)